# Injecting instructions to the byte code

Tags: java

I need to inject below code some other class file can any one help me to inject this code

```
long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.gc();
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
double memoryUsage=(double)memory/MEGABYTE;
```

Comment: This code does nothing except calling gc(), which is generally useless. Why would you go the very hard road of injecting byte-code in classes only to inject useless code, that should be run in your own code BTW?

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler.  It is designed to do this sort of thing.

Comment: For manipulating byte code at class run/loading time you can use http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/